Character table for non abelian group of order $8$ over $\mathbb C$
I am trying to determine the character table for non abelian group of order $8$ over $\mathbb C$.
Let $G$ be the non abelian group of order $8$. I have proved that there are four $1$-dimensional irreducible representations and one $2$-dimensional irreducible representations. And I have already solved the following:
Let $e$ be the identity in $G$, $g \in C(G)\backslash \{e\}$, and $C_3,C_4,C_5$ be the other three conjugacy classes. Let $\chi_1,\cdots,\chi_4$ be the four $1$-dimensional irreducible representations, and $\chi_1=1$. And let $\chi$ be the $2$-dimensional irreducible representation. I have got this table:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
 & \{e\} & \{g\} & C_3 & C_4 & C_5 \\
 \chi_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \chi_2 & 1 & 1  &  &  & \\
   \chi_3 & 1 & 1 & & &  \\
    \chi_4 & 1 & 1 & & &  \\
     \chi & 2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$
But I have difficulty in continuing.
I have these equations:
$$ \langle \chi_k,\chi_k\rangle=1 \Rightarrow |\chi_k(C_3)|^2+|\chi_k(C_4)|^2+|\chi_k(C_5)|^2=3, k=2,3,4, $$
which means that $|\chi_k(C_j)|=1, k=2,3,4,j=3,4,5$, and therefore they are all fourth roots of unity.
I also have $$\chi_k(C_3)+\chi_k(C_4)+\chi_k(C_5)=-1, k=2,3,4, $$
and $$\chi_2(C_j)+\chi_3(C_j)+\chi_4(C_j)=-1, j=3,4,5. $$
But I cannot work out why can't $\chi_2(C_3)=i, \chi_2(C_4)=-i $ and $\chi_2(C_5)=-1$.
Many thanks in advance!

Both $D_4$ and $Q_8$. (I think their character tables are the same. )

If you know that the possible groups you are looking at are $D_4$ and $Q_8$ then you know that modulo the centre each has a quotient $C_2\times C_2$ and the character table of $C_2\times C_2$ is what you are looking for. (You'd only get $i$'s if the quotient were $C_4$ whihc is impossible).

@ancientmathematician: Thanks for your comments. Yes I know that $G/C(G)\cong C_2\times C_2$. But I do not know the relationship between the character table of $G/C(G)$ and the character table of $G$. Can you explain  more in detail?

In general if we have a homomorphism $f:G/N \to X$ then we also can construct a homomorphism $F:G\to X$ such that $N$ is in the kernel of $F$ and $F(x)=f(xN)$.
